# Folder permissions changed automatically

Tags: 12.10, permissions, directory

Hey guys first of all I searched a lot on this site but didnt get any exact answer to my questions.
Dont know something happened automatically and all the folders permissions changed automatically and there came a lock icon on all of my folders and files.
Then I searched on this site and got the solution as this command

```
sudo chown 777 -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

It solved my problem half way, it removed the lock icon but now all folders permissions are read only so please guide me how to reset all the folder permissions as it was previously?

I'm using ubuntu 12.10

Thanks

Comment: But as its read only now, Im not able to do anything...I think it changed the owner or something...please help me out guys...

Answer (score 3):

### **DONT DO THIS!**

You have written that you have done `sudo chown 777 -R ${USER}:${USER} ${HOME}`

#### 1. Problem

Your are using `sudo` to do an operation which should normally change resources you're controlling with your current user. This is extremely unsafe.

#### 2. Problem

You are using sudo and environment variables.
This may lead you in to an error situation. For illustration try the following.

- `sudo echo $USER`  --> e.g. shivam
- `sudo echo '$USER'` --> **root**

#### 3. Problem

`chown` will change the ownership of a file.
Luckily you have add a failure. The parameter `777` would be identified as user name that is not existing and the file ${USER}:${USER} is not found.

The command `chmod` is responsible for changing file or directory permissions.

### Fixing the permissions of all folders below a distinct directory.

Use the following to change the folder permissions below a distinct directory:

```
find BASEDIR -type d -exec chmod u+rwx \{\} \;
```

In your case replace `BASEDIR` with `~`. For the bash `~` will be replaced with the home directory of the current user.

This will process only directories (not files) and set the *read*, *write* and *enter* (aka *execute*) permissions for the owner of the directory.

For more informations please read `man chmod`

Notes:

- Be careful with the *recursive* option `-R` because it will process all directories and **files** below the given directory.
- Use the *symbolic* permission notation like `u+rwx`, because it is easier to understand.
- Don't use `sudo` if you`re not realy need it.

### Check that your filesystem is mounted correctly

Ensure that the partition containing the problematic home directory is mounted *read-write*.

```
  grep /home /proc/mounts
```

This should give an similar output:

> /dev/mapper/system-home /home ext4 **rw**,relatime,discard,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0

If the **rw** option is not shown, then the partition is mounted for some reasons (e.g. inconsistency) read only.
If this is the case invoke a file system check.
This is normally also invoked during the boot of your computer.

Comment: can you guide me with BASEDIR ?? ..Im new to linux

Comment: These are the results :

shivamd@shivam:~$ grep /home /proc/mounts  
shivamd@shivam:~$ /dev/mapper/system-home /home ext4 rw,relatime,discard,commit=600,data=ordered 0 0
bash: /dev/mapper/system-home: No such file or directory
shivamd@shivam:~$

Comment: I think first time I tried this command without 777
sudo chown 777 -R ${USER}:${USER} ${HOME} like
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ${HOME}

Comment: Nopes actually I used that tool and replaced it with my home directory name...But it gave me error as directory not found I ran this command : find shivamd -type d -exec chmod u+rwx \{\} \;

Comment: `sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ${HOME}` not good, but likely it hasn't scramled anything because normally $USER:USER is the right ownership for user and group of any item below the user home directory.

Comment: For the BASEDIR see again the updated answer.

Comment: hey guess what my system got restarted due to power failure, error /tmp corrupt or does not exists, selected automatic recovery...woaaaaaaa Im back with fully working OS...Linux rocks,,, but my hibernate/shut down takes hell lotta time, any solution?

Comment: Provide a new question with detailed informations ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that all of your files are in a state that, however readable now, they are pretty unusable.

The problem with setting permissions by hand is that not all files have the same permission set (think about your ssh-keys for instance, you don't want somebody else be able to read them) so you are in a messy situation where you have to decide for every single file which permissions they should have.

The best thing you can do is create a new account and copy the files you need from the old account. Permissions will then be set automatically. Also if you need your personal settings  you can copy them also from your old account. They are in hidden files or hidden directories in your home directory. Be careful to only copy what you need.

Also it might be wise to do a filesystemcheck afterwards.